# Angular 2 : How to get the options based on dropdown values

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am trying to create a dynamic dropdown based on json response.

Response

```
Array(3)
        0:
        val_id:1
        role_id:1
        id:1
        is_optional:false
        is_text:false


        1:
        val_id:1
        role_id:1
        id: 2
        is_optional:false
        is_text:false


        2:
        val_id:1
        role_id:1
        id :3
        is_optional: false
        is_text: false
```

HTML

```
   <p class="">Questions</p>

       <div *ngFor="let question of response">
       <select class="dropdown" [(ngModel)]="questions">
       <option *ngFor = "************">{{option?.name}}</option>
        </select>

  </div>
```

However, I created three questions(based on response), each question contain dropdown, now how to call the method to get options for particular dropdown depend on question Id. each dropdown contain different options.

Please help me.

Comment: Think the best option is to have **ngModelOnChange** and with that call a function that refresh your options.

Comment: Yes..but ngModelOnChange not working.